# Accessing grid elements programmatically

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp

Let's say I have:

```
<Grid Name="paramGrid">
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition/>
        <RowDefinition/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

    <TextBox Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0"/>
    <TextBox Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0"/>
</Grid>
```

I am aware of how to add rows/columns such as:

```
paramGrid.RowDefinitions.Add(new RowDefinition());

TextBox tb = new TextBox();
tb.Text = "Sample";
tb.Name = "textBox";

paramGrid.Children.Add(tb);
Grid.SetColumn(tb, 0);
Grid.SetRow(tb, 2);
```

The above adds a `TextBox` to the new row.

My question is: How would I go about accessing it now? I need to query the `.Text` property of the `TextBox` on the new row.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Keep a ref to the textbox:

```
private TextBox m_Tb;

...

m_Tb = new TextBox();
m_Tb.Text = "Sample";
m_Tb.Name = "textBox";

....

something something = m_Tb.Text;
```

Find it in the grid's `Children` collection:

```
var tb = (TextBox)paramGrid.Children[0];
something something = tb.Text;
```

Obviously `[0]` will only work if the text box is either the only child in the grid or the first one.